# how to change the marked date to one user chose

Tags: datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

when using datepicker (jquery ui 1.10.3) it opens up with default highlight on today and that's fine.
Now, the user want to choose other date - but the initial highlight still remains on today.

I'm searching in their documentation and in general  (newbie in js and all) and can't reach the answer..

Edit - this is weird cause according to their example it should work out of the box http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#inline

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to add a class to a datepicker-wrapping element when the user selects a date and adjust the CSS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#txtDate').datepicker({
       onSelect: function() {
           $("#txtDate").addClass("madeSelect");           
       }
    });
});
```

Necessary CSS adjustment for `.ui-datepicker-today` : set the background to the background-image of the default-date according to the theme you're using.

Necessary CSS adjustment for `.ui-datepicker-today.ui-datepicker-current-day` (in case the user selects the current day): set the background to the theme's background-image of `.ui-datepicker-current-day` and the color of the font to your theme's color for the current day.

```
.madeSelect .ui-datepicker-today .ui-state-highlight
{
background: url("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/sunny/images/ui-bg_gloss-wave_60_fece2f_500x100.png") repeat-x scroll 50% 50% #fece2f;
}
.madeSelect .ui-datepicker-today.ui-datepicker-current-day .ui-state-highlight
{
background: url("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/sunny/images/ui-bg_inset-soft_30_ffffff_1x100.png") repeat-x scroll 50% 50% #ffffff;;
color: #0074c7;
}
```

Working Demo here: [Datepicker - remove highlight on today when date is selected](http://jsfiddle.net/nhLzu28e/1/)